# Hide the content under transparent fixed navbar while scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

the problem:
I have transparent fixed navbar with some gap (margin-top) and below content, which is located under the navbar while scrolling down globally. The problem is that navbar is transparent and the background of the page is a dynamic slideshow of different images so I can't use z-index and hide it by changing background color or put image same as background..

**In conclusion:**

- Transparent fixed navbar with gap
- Dynamic images background
- It has to be global scrolling (can't use scrolling for div content)
- I'am using bootstrap 3

**Drawings:**

WRONG: [How its looks now][1]

RIGHT: [How it should be][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwc1h.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Sbd.png
```

Sorry for problems with understanding me, here is code:
http://jsfiddle.net/5myw4e26/

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please rephrase for clarity?

Comment: Well along with theory we would love to see some code as well or a better version in jsfiddle problem demo.

Comment: Please read the 'How to ask'. Any code you already have would help us. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry: here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/5myw4e26/

Comment: I can do it easily: https://jsfiddle.net/ypm56kdy/

Comment: Yes, because you utilize inner div (#b). I need it for **global scrolling** (no inner divs overflow-y: scroll)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a position fixed at your navbar you can do a top div empty with float left and a height with the size of your navbar.

Comment: But still If I will scroll down the content It will meet soon or later my navbar.

Comment: But then that div will scroll up, if the page scrolls. Causing the content to be visible below it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to accomplish what you we're trying to do. It's probably not the best solution, but it works.

Using JQuery I calculated when a paragraph (`p.content`) and the `navigation-bar` collided.

There's more than enough to finetune, so you can adjust it to your needs.

***JQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).scroll(function() {
        $("p").each(function() {
          if ($(this).offset().top <= $(document).scrollTop() + 32) {
            $(this).css("opacity", "0");
          } else {
            $(this).css("opacity", "1");
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

*Note that the 32 in `$(this).offset().top <= $(document).scrollTop() + 32`  is the height of the navigation bar.*

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    $("p").each(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top <= $(document).scrollTop() + 32) {
        $(this).css("opacity", "0");
      } else {
        $(this).css("opacity", "1");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-height: 2000px;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
p.content {
  margin: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: yellow;
}
p:first-of-type {
  margin: 44px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    Navigation Bar
  </nav>
  <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed dolor metus. Morbi tristique nisl vel lectus rutrum, non ultricies dolor feugiat. Fusce nec dolor in purus consectetur lacinia non sit amet turpis. Donec facilisis tortor mauris, nec vulputate
    massa fermentum vel. Praesent in neque quis lacus hendrerit tincidunt sed et dolor. Nullam fermentum, orci at pulvinar imperdiet, lacus libero facilisis ante, sit amet venenatis sem tortor in nibh. Ut ullamcorper porta fermentum. Praesent faucibus,
    erat eget iaculis porttitor, purus purus posuere nulla, eget lacinia odio libero in lectus. Vivamus sem ex, commodo ac tortor ut, fringilla vulputate eros. Ut iaculis augue non ipsum porttitor ornare.</p>
  <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce facilisis tellus luctus ornare hendrerit. Curabitur hendrerit justo ante. Maecenas scelerisque ligula condimentum, aliquam tortor sit amet, aliquam lacus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
    ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut ut augue vel massa tempus laoreet. Nulla porttitor, sem ac aliquet facilisis, purus ligula pulvinar ipsum, quis volutpat enim elit sed ante. Pellentesque quis diam vestibulum, viverra elit at, sollicitudin mi. Vivamus
    vehicula ex eu justo feugiat, a ullamcorper nisi commodo. Phasellus sed tortor eget purus mollis tempor at sit amet libero. Fusce tincidunt est est, tristique pretium justo feugiat eget. Donec et lacus vehicula, aliquam sapien a, eleifend tortor.</p>

  <p class="content">Vivamus vitae placerat elit. Integer eleifend nibh at purus suscipit rutrum. Aliquam et fermentum mauris. Aenean gravida velit a vehicula aliquet. Duis neque tortor, luctus eget condimentum eget, venenatis eget lorem. Maecenas sed ullamcorper tellus.
    Donec euismod bibendum nunc, non ullamcorper neque cursus eget. Curabitur dapibus orci non quam vestibulum ornare. Aenean tincidunt interdum justo faucibus feugiat. Proin molestie lorem ultricies neque consequat, commodo cursus nisl molestie. Donec
    gravida viverra nisl, consectetur laoreet libero interdum ac. Vivamus varius vestibulum quam eu rutrum. Pellentesque id rhoncus massa.</p>

  <p class="content">Nunc finibus leo mollis efficitur tempus. Suspendisse ac elit lectus. Proin auctor ipsum faucibus arcu cursus congue. Nam rutrum odio non enim euismod auctor id in justo. Ut non sagittis orci, vel tincidunt elit. Mauris odio sem, varius eget tortor
    at, commodo pretium massa. Cras sed rhoncus dolor, non dictum sem. Curabitur in imperdiet turpis, in imperdiet mi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Maecenas erat nisl, sagittis id eleifend ut, consequat eget orci. Aenean
    blandit arcu non varius ornare.</p>

  <p class="content">Pellentesque molestie consectetur lectus in iaculis. Curabitur efficitur ac nisi vitae eleifend. Morbi semper tristique ornare. Morbi in cursus mauris. Morbi et risus velit. Etiam lobortis commodo dolor, ac pulvinar dolor gravida vel. Donec sollicitudin
    metus urna, eu consequat magna vehicula a. Vivamus interdum, enim non consequat ultrices, lacus enim vehicula ante, vitae tristique tellus nibh sit amet eros. Aliquam consequat eu orci id rutrum. Donec lacus eros, eleifend et viverra vitae, congue
    at turpis. Quisque rhoncus fermentum ex sed lobortis. Fusce luctus, lorem vitae condimentum gravida, nibh tortor elementum nulla, id auctor nisl ex eu lectus. Donec auctor ligula sem, et porttitor neque eleifend vitae. Aliquam felis lacus, sollicitudin
    laoreet dui mollis, scelerisque auctor metus.</p>
</div>
```